# Process Monitoring

Tags: c#, process

I'm quite familiar with the System.Diagnostics.Process class. But, I'm wondering about how I can monitor a specific process (i.e. Check to see if it's running every XX mins/secs). I need to be able to checking whether a process is running and if it is, continue with initialising the rest of the program.

Thanks,
-Zack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you didn't start the process yourself, you get find the `Process` object associated with a process by looking through the list returned by [`Process.GetProcessesByName(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname.aspx) or [`Process.GetProcesses(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocesses.aspx)

Once you have the process, you can listen read its properties (including [`HasExited`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited.aspx)) and (as Jon mentions in his response) if you set [`EnableRaisingEvents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.enableraisingevents.aspx) you can listen to its events (including [`Exited`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx)).

Answer (score 5):

Checking if it's still running is easy: [`Process.HasExited`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited.aspx).

Rather than polling this periodically, however, you could set [`EnableRaisingEvents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.enableraisingevents.aspx) to true, and attach a handler to the [`Exited`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx) event.

EDIT: To answer the question in the comment about "fetching" the process - that depends on what you already know. If you know its process ID, you could use [`Process.GetProcessById`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessbyid.aspx). If you only know its name, you would have to use [`Process.GetProcessesByName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname.aspx) and work out what to do if you get multiple results. If you don't know the *exact* name, you could use [`Process.GetProcesses`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocesses.aspx) and look for whatever you *do* know about it. Those options are effectively in order of preference :)

Comment: What about fetching the actual process and see if it's running?

Comment: Thanks, I actually did a combination of yours and Daniel's solutions.

Comment: if my application has unhandled exeption and dont close process but freez and no response how can get status?

Comment: @PeymanTahmasebi: Sorry, that comment is rather hard to understand. Perhaps you want to ask a separate - but more detailed - question?

Answer (score -1):

Something like this, maybe?

```
        Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

        bool found = false;
        foreach (Process theprocess in processlist)
        {
            if(theprocess.ProcessName == "YourProcessName")
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!found)
        {
            return;
        }
```