# Can EnableRaisingEvents be used on a process that is already running at the time my application starts?

Tags: c#, winforms

Currently I have a program that starts another application and monitors that application to keep it running using this code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process startProgram =
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("program.exe", String.Format(Program.ConnectionArg));
startProgram.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
startProgram.SynchronizingObject = this;
startProgram.Exited += this.PrematureClose;
```

However my concern is what happens if my program is somehow killed. Is it possible to use the `EnableRaisingEvents` and `startProgram.Exited` when my program restarts?

I have a feeling I might need to ditch my code in favor of some sort of timer loop that checks if the process is still running.

EDIT 08-10-2016:

So I have tried the following code and VS based on [Process Monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703176/process-monitoring)

What it's telling me:

> cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Diagnostics.Process[]' to 'System.Diagnostics.Process'

```
System.Diagnostics.Process program_open_check = 
    System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("program");
program_open_check.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
program_open_check.SynchronizingObject = this;
```

Comment: You could of course refire the app if your monitor finds it missing, therefore it would restart with the raisingevents enabled

Comment: Have you tried to run this code? maybe that way you'll find out...
Try to crash the app on purpose by throwing an exception or killing the process

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703176/process-monitoring

Comment: @PeterDuniho I went to that thread and tried the code out and it did not work.

Comment: _"it did not work"_ -- it would have if you'd used it correctly. I've tested the basic technique myself, just to be sure, and I assure you it does. The phrase "it did not work" is not actionable; there's no useful information in it to guide anyone trying to help. If you need help, please fix your question so that it includes a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces whatever problem you are having, as well as a precise description of what the code does, and what you want it to do instead.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I added an edit section to my question with the code I tried and the error.

Comment: Please re-read [mcve]. You don't seem to have understood its guidance. In the meantime, keep in mind that process names aren't unique. You are calling a method that returns an array and trying to assign the result to a non-array variable. That's obviously illegal. If you want to watch a specific process, you need a way to identifying which process named "program" it is you really want to watch. Alternatively, maybe you want to watch all of them. Either way, you need to handle the array correctly.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Well I assumed it was something of that nature. What method do I use then to look at one specific process? I know there should be only one instance of this process running so I assume I would grab the process ID in someway. I am very new to C# and Java so any help or examples or links with example code would be nice. I learn best from examples and seeing how things work.

Comment: _"What method do I use then to look at one specific process"_ -- you can look at an individual `Process` the same way you would look at any individual element of an array: by using the `[]` indexing syntax to retrieve the element of interest and using that value however you like. _"I know there should be only one instance of this process running"_ -- if you are _sure_ there will only ever be one instance, you can just use something like `Process.GetProcessesByName("program")[0]`.

Comment: If there any possibility at all there could be more than one, and you care which one you are looking at, then you need to figure out a way to distinguish which one to use. _"any help or examples or links with example code would be nice"_ -- that's what your favorite web search engine is for. Stack Overflow is for asking questions about specific programming problems. Requests for pointers to tutorials, code examples, documentation, etc. are all expressly off-topic, as it's assumed users know enough about the Internet to perform those searches themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually solved this and forgot to post.

So, the big issue was the process object was getting disposed since it was being used as part of a using block. The code below is the a solid way of doing this. Alternatively you could define a function directly instead of using a delegate.

```
        Process[] processes_array = Process.GetProcessesByName("someprogram");
        foreach (Process some_process in processes_array)
        {
            some_process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            some_process.Exited += delegate (object sender, EventArgs args)
            {
                // Do work.
                // DISPOSE PROCESS IF NOT USING IT AFTER THIS!!
            };
        }
```